# Preventing DBIx::Class from calling everything related to a new, not-yet-inserted row?

Tags: perl, orm, dbix-class

I have a parent/child relationship in my schema. I'd like to use very similar code to modify an existing parent as to create a new one. The edit case is easy to find the children:

```
my $parent = $resultset->find($parent_id);
my @children = $parent->children->all
```

However, in the new case, something weird happens:

```
my $parent = $resultset->new_result({});
my @children = $parent->children->all;
```

I expected to have `@children` to be empty, but instead I got back *all* children, regardless of parent.

I can do something like this (for each related-record accessor, *vomit*):

```
sub children {
    my $self = shift;

    my $res = $self->next::method(@_);
    my $parent_no = $self->get_column('parent_no');
    defined $parent_no ? $res : $res->search({1 => 2});

}
```

Please tell me the right way to do this, as the above mustn't be it.

**version:** 0.08010, because that's what Debian Lenny has (and what our production servers are running)

Comment: Why not use DBIx::Class::Tree to maintain the parent/child relationship?

Comment: @jrockway: (1) Using experimental modules in production code doesn't seem like a good idea; (2) parent and child are not the same type, they're completely different tables. This isn't a recursive parent/child relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of DBIx::Class are you using? I'm running the most recent version, 0.08112, and I can't seem to find a new_record method for ResultSet. There is, however, a [new_result](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSet.pm#new_result) method that looks like it would have the same effect as the new_record method you are using. I tried the following code and got an empty array, as expected:

```
my $parent = $resultset->new_result({});
my @children = $parent->children();
```

Also, according to the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Relationship.pm#has_many) for a has_many Relationship, the created accessor method will return objects in list context, so you don't need to call all. I did try it the way you have it though, and @children was still empty.

Comment: I'm using 0.08010, because that's whats in Debian Lenny (which our production servers are running) has.

Comment: Well, I did a quick workaround until I can upgrade. I found that fix in the changelog.